# "Screen position out of view frustum" in Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to dynamically set the position and size of my camera in my scene,If I execute the below code the error occurs.It works fine if I set the properties in my scene,so the error is in my code

> **Error :** Screen position out of view frustum (screen pos 959.000000, 454.000000) (Camera rect 0 0 960 907)
>   UnityEngine.SendMouseEvents:DoSendMouseEvents(Int32)

```
using UnityEngine;
public class CameraInt : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera cam1;
    private int row, col;
    private float size;
    void Start()
    {
        MazeLoader ml = gameObject.AddComponent<MazeLoader>();
        row = ml.mazeRows;
        col = ml.mazeColumns;
        size = ml.size;
        float r = row * size / 2;
        cam1.transform.Translate(new Vector3(r, 0,col*size/2),Space.World);
        cam1.orthographicSize = r;
    }
}
```

- Camera View : Orthographic
- Unity version : 2019.3.13f1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error occurs if camera **size** is set to **0**

this line was the cause of error :
`cam1.orthographicSize = r;`

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Happened to me when I multiplied it by Time.timeScale so the scaling would stop in pause menu. This error could've been more descriptive.